# How do I count how many projects are over budget?

Tags: mysql, view

I need to identity how many projects are over their hourly budget for each department. I have set it up so that I subtracted the total amount of hours worked by the max allotted hours and if the number is positive then the project is over budget.

it is shown as:

```
| Department | ProjectMaxHours | TotalHoursWorked | Balance |

| Marketing  |          135.00 |           160.00 |   25.00 |
| Finance    |          120.00 |            85.00 |  -35.00 |
| Accounting |          145.00 |           130.00 |  -15.00 |
| Marketing  |          150.00 |           165.00 |   15.00 |
| Finance    |          140.00 |            52.50 |  -87.50
```

I am now wanting to create another view from this view that would list Marking has 2 overspent projects, Finance has 0 and Accounting has 0.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
create view overspent as
  select department, count(*) as num_over_projects
  from hours
  where balance > 0
  group by department
```

Comment: I think you're missing the word `view` there on the 1st line.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   sum(cnt),
         Department
from     (select 0 as cnt,
                 Department
          from   [hours]
          where  Balance < 0
          union all
          select 1,
                 Department
          from   [hours]
          where  Balance > 0) as g
group by Department;
```